# how should i represent tabular data in json file

Tags: jquery, json

I want to represent tabular data in json file. I want to read this json file using datatable ajaxsource tag as shown below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "sources/abc.json"
     });
});
```

tabular data is

```
Name      Age      City
sam        23       Mexico
Mike       29       Newyork
Sydney     24       London
```

How should I represent this data in json file????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An exemple of JSON source for the plugin dataTable:

```
{ "aaData":[
    ["sam","23","Mexico"],
    ["Mike","29","NewYork"],
    ["Sydney","24","London"]
]}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[{"Name":"sam","Age":"23","City":"Mexico"},
{"Name":"Mike","Age":"29","City":"London"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tabular data in can be represented in JSON as an Array of JSON objects where each object is a row.

```
COL1     COL2     COL3
________________________
DATA11   DATA12   DATA13
DATA21   DATA22   DATA23
```

Can be represented in Json as

```
[{"COL1":"DATA11","COL2":"DATA12","COL3":"DATA13"},{"COL1":"DATA21","COL2":"DATA22","COL3":"DATA23"}]
```